# I hit a hotkey and something happened to my sculpt and i dont know what it is

Tags: sculpting

[image]
I hit a hotkey and I'm not sure what it is and how to undo it, please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark but it looks like your Normals got inverted?

If that's the case go-to edit mode select all of the vertices then navigate over to
Mesh>Normals>Recalculate outside